# Jquery animate from ... to ... (анимация от и до)

Tags: jquery, animate

Слабовато пока знаком с Jquery, сам найти ответ не сумел, возможно не там ищу. Насколько я понял функция animate() принимает только конечные значения атрибутов стиля.

Как можно реализовать такое?

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#test" ).animate({
    // from left: -100
    // to left: 0
  }, 500, function() {
    // действие по завершении
  });
});
```

Вариант ниже, к сожалению, не подойдет, так как вызов нескольких анимаций подряд будет работать криво.

```
$( "#test" ).css('left', -100).animate({      
  left: 0
}, 500, function() {
  // действие по завершении
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {

  $('#test').queue(function () {
    $(this).css('left', -100);
    $(this).dequeue(); 
  });   

  $( "#test" ).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 500, function() {
    // действие по завершении
  });
});
```